# Spring Boot Websocket Security with Angular 5

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I am trying to implement websockets in my SpringBoot + Angular 5 application.
I followed [this](https://medium.com/oril/spring-boot-websockets-angular-5-f2f4b1c14cee) tutorial. The code works fine without spring security. But doesn't work with Spring Security. I posted the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131269/spring-boot-angular-5-websocket). The comment didn't help much. I am still getting these errors on the client

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost/socket/446/qvjiwvgt/websocket.

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at https://localhost/socket/446/kwabmpm0/eventsource.

Error: Incompatibile SockJS! Main site uses: "1.1.5", the iframe: "1.0.0".


 Whoops! Lost connection to https://localhost/socket.
```

and the console log on the server is

```
2018-08-03 10:25:25.030  WARN 17952 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported
2018-08-03 10:25:25.030  WARN 17952 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
2018-08-03 10:25:25.046  WARN 17952 --- [-nio-443-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
2018-08-03 10:25:25.905  WARN 17952 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported
2018-08-03 10:25:25.905  WARN 17952 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

**Here is the front End**

**WebsocketService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AsyncDataService } from './async-data.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import * as SockJs from 'sockjs-client';
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';

@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService {

  constructor(private asyncDataService: AsyncDataService, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  public connect() {
    const socket = new SockJs('/socket');

    const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    return stompClient;
  }
}
```

**WebSokcetComponent.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { WebSocketService } from './../web-socket.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-web-socket',
  templateUrl: './web-socket.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./web-socket.component.css']
})
export class WebSocketComponent implements OnInit {
  public notifications = 0;
  constructor(private websocketService: WebSocketService, private http: HttpClient) {
    const stompClient = this.websocketService.connect();
    stompClient.connect({}, frame => {

      // Subscribe to notification topic
      stompClient.subscribe('/topic/notification', notifications => {
        this.notifications = JSON.parse(notifications.body).count;
      });

    });
  }
  getNotification(){
    this.http.get("/notify");
  }
  ngOnInit(){

  }
}
```

and the BackEnd

**WebSocketConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

    registry.addEndpoint("/socket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");

    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
```

**WebsocketSecurityConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.messaging.MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
    messages.anyMessage().permitAll();
    }

}
```

NotificationsController.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class NotificationController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    // Initialize Notifications
    private Notifications notifications = new Notifications(0);

    @GetMapping("/notify")
   // @SendTo("/topic/notification")
    public void getNotification() {
    System.out.println("Request received..");
    // Increment Notification by one
    notifications.increment();

    // Push notifications to front-end
    template.convertAndSend("/topic/notification", notifications);
    System.out.println("Response Sent..");
    // return notifications;
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
// Only websocket related code posted here
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.httpBasic().disable();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/socket/**").permitAll();
}
```

Help me fix the problem here...

Comment: `Lost connection to https://localhost/socket`. Are you sure your server runs on port 80? Are you serving frontend and the backend via the same webserver?

Comment: yes. front end is served from the same web server. It's served from the static folder. It runs both on 80 and 443 as it is configured with ssl and i am able to access other endpoints

Comment: Hmm, I've haven't used Spring's WebSocket support with HTTPS yet, not sure about if that could have effect on anything. If I were you I'd try dropping HTTPS just to test if it works that way. If it does my guess you'd need to configure the web socket to be exposed over HTTPS

Comment: It didn't work even over http.

Comment: Well,.could you create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The problem is getting vaguer by the minute like this :)

Comment: All the code posted above is involved in the whole websocket setup. How do I make it more minimal? It is already a piece of a bunch of code

Comment: Make it [self-contained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665651/spring-boot-websocket-security-with-angular-5). It always helped to get to the right solution (by myself) by making as small an example as I could. Maybe zip the projects, push it to GitHub. Whatever. The goal for me when asking anything here is to always try and help whoever wants to help me by reducing "friction". Not having the same codebase (even if it's really sample) as you introduces lots of "guesses" into the formula, which not helps. Hope I made sense.